# receiving [object Object] when appending html from r server

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I an trying to simply append a div from the server file using the below code

```
    HTML("content-id",div("title", "Hello"), add = TRUE)
```

but it keeps returning

```
    [object Object]
```

Is there anything i can do to fix this? I've tried using

```
     HTML("content-id",tags$div("title", "Hello"), add = TRUE)
```

but the effect is the same. Any help would be great.  Thank you!

Comment: I've also tried shinyjs, but same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm, figured it out i think!

```
    shinyjs::html("content-id",as.character(tags$div("title", "Hello"), add = TRUE))
```

Comment: If what you're trying to do is CHANGE the HTML of a specific element, then yes that's the correct function, from my shinyjs package. The HTML function is from shiny (or perhaps htmltools?) and has a completely different usage -- it's used to mark a piece of code as HTML instead of plain text

Comment: yea, thanks for your comment! i realize my question is talking about two separate functions, and i did not make that clear.. I really appreciate the help!